# Converting String to TimeStamp using .valueOf() adds zero at the end of time

Tags: java, postgresql

When I convert this String to TimeStamp by using the method TimeStamp.valueOf(string), it adds '**.0**' at the end of TimeStamp. However I want it in the same format as of string but the data type should be TimeStamp.

```
String myStr = "2021-08-25 09:46:26";
TimeStamp dateTime = TimeStamp.valueOf(mystr);
```

> `returns 2021-08-25 09:46:26.0`

I've also tried SimpleDateFormat with pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but it also ruins the format.

Comment: Then you will have `0` milliseconds, because that is how a `TimeStamp` records time. At the millisecond level. And with that format. And you cannot change it.

Comment: The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object. You can get a formatted `String` value using a formatter.